# How do I change the default program for Preview in the context menu when uploading images to websites in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, context-menu

I'm not asking how to change the default program for a certain file extension, but how do I change the behavior of this particular context menu item?  I've gone through various answers and search results that recommended context menu editors and various registry edits, but none of them address this particular item.  I want to be able to preview certain gifs that I upload, but Windows Photo Viewer doesn't animate gifs.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I am sure it is possible, though another thought - maybe add a 'sendto' item - it would kind of do a similar thing, though not directly the one you asked about.

Comment: maybe one of these tools might help: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/remove-click-context-menu-items-editors

Comment: Yeah that's what I referred to before, I've been to that same page and none of those editors or instructions deal with this particularly annoying Preview entry unfortunately.

Comment: I figured so, just haven't seen this specific one, maybe SendTo might be the fastest workaround for a time.

Comment: @user347519 You mean you want to preview in `Internet Explorer` or any third party `GIF viewer` (with animation) while you click the context menu `Preview`??

Comment: I want to preview a file with a program other than Windows Photo Viewer when I am uploading to any browser in Windows 7 via the context menu.

Answer (score 4):

## Solution

The **Preview** context menu item can be overridden. Here's how:

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type or paste `regedit.exe` in the text box, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. Navigate to the following registry key:

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts
   ```
3. Check if there's a subkey that matches the extension you're interested in, e.g. `.gif`. Expand the extension subkey, and see if there's a `UserChoice` key.

   - Double-click the `ProgId` value, and copy its content.
   - In case either keys are missing, expand the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` key, and locate the extension-related subkey. Double-click the `(Default)` value, and copy its content.
4. Select the following registry key:

   ```
   HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
   ```

   Click the **Edit > Find** menu, and paste the value you copied earlier in the text box. After unchecking the **Values** and **Data** options, enable the **Match whole string only** option. Then click the **Find Next** button.
5. Once the target key is located, expand it. Right-click the `shell` subkey, and choose **New > Key** from the context menu. Name the key `preview`.

   **Note** In case you're getting an error stating you don't have enough permissions, log on with an administrator account to perform the required changes.
6. Right-click an empty spot in the right pane, and choose **New > Expandable String Value** from the context menu. Name the new registry value `MUIVerb`, double-click it, and set it like this:

   ```
   @%ProgramFiles%\Windows Photo Viewer\photoviewer.dll,-3043
   ```

   **Note** In Windows Vista the path is slightly different, and the value needs to be adjusted accordingly:

   ```
   @%ProgramFiles%\Windows Photo Gallery\photoviewer.dll,-3043
   ```
7. Right-click the `preview` key, and choose **New > Key** from the context menu. Name it `command`.
8. Double-click the `(Default)` value in the right pane, and set it something like this:

   ```
   "X:\Path\to\program.exe" "%1"
   ```
9. Repeat steps 2-8 for any other file extensions you want to tweak.